# How to access and change an HTML control's value in an ASP.NET MVC action without returning to the view?

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc

Is it possible to set an HTML control's value directly from the action in ASP.NET?
I'm used to UWP app development and the way we do this is to simply select the control by name and just set it's value to whatever we want it to be, is there a similar way of doing that?
I've created a simple POC.
CS:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(TestViewModel model)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < model.Counter; i++)
    {
        Thread.Sleep(1000);
        // lblCounter should take the counter's value here, maybe something like lblCounter.Text = i.ToString(); :P
    }
    return View();
}
```

View:

```
@model LiveCounterPOC.Models.TestViewModel
@using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Home", FormMethod.Post))
{
    @Html.TextBoxFor(p=>p.Counter);
    <input type="submit" value="Start Counter" />
}
<label id="lblCounter"></label>
```

Model:

```
public class TestViewModel
{
    public int Counter { get; set; }
}
```

I know I have to use an ajax function, but i'm not sure when to call it or what is should it be.
Thanks

Comment: This is not even close to how ASP.NET MVC works. You might want to look into WebForms instead, but even that won't do what you want. It's simply not how the HTTP protocol works.

Comment: @Blindy so it can't be done huh?

Comment: The answer to your question is What are you trying to achieve? Value of control in your sample is set when view is being rendered. What is the problem with that?

Comment: In general you can assign value to control the way you want it with signalr.

Answer (score 0):

You can't access the View controls from within the action method in MVC, this is not how MVC works.